# Can any one help how to allow the manual date in bootstrap-datepicker plugin

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

here my code

```
 <div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#datepic .input-group.date').datepicker({

});
```

Right now i can set the date with popup select, but i need user can allow to entry the date manual as well as using popup

Comment: Hi, hope this one useful for you 
https://jsfiddle.net/onlinesolution/ap6dwpmz/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, hope will work for you and try below click also for you reference

https://jsfiddle.net/onlinesolution/ap6dwpmz/

```
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>


$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ constrainInput: false });
```